# Feed a QList with another

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

hi i'm trying to send a QList as a parameter to another class but for some reason i got a read access violation...

**CompareTimeChannel.h**

```
 class CompareTimeChannel : public IDataChannel
   public:

      // @brief The method used to receive the list
      void setData(const QList< QSharedPointer<core::ITrackSection> > & sections);

      // @brief The list
      QList< QSharedPointer<core::ITrackSection> > _sections;

 };
```

**CompareTimeChannel.cpp**

```
 // @brief Empty constructor
 CompareTimeChannel::CompareTimeChannel()
 {
 }

 void CompareTimeChannel::setData(const QList< QSharedPointer<core::ITrackSection> > & sections)
 {
     //_sections = *new QList< QSharedPointer<core::ITrackSection> > ();
     _sections.clear();
     _sections.append(sections);
 }
```

Running this code will throw `Exception at 0x31cc78d, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x4, flags=0x0` on `_sections.clear();`

I tried to initialize the list before (the commented line `_sections = *new QList<...>`) but the exception is thrown the same.

An answer would be very appreciated...

**EDIT**

Ok it's fixed!

First, like @AndreasT said, i had to initialize the default QList constructor.

Then, according to @10WaRRioR01 's answer, the issue comes from `CompareTimeChannel` which wasn't initialized the first time the method was called. Fixed using :

```
        CompareTimeChannel* chan = static_cast<CompareTimeChannel*>(channel);
        Q_ASSERT(chan);
        if (chan) {
            chan->setData(sections);
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "Dynamic cast failure";
        }
```

Thank you all, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//_sections = *new QList< QSharedPointer<core::ITrackSection> > ();
```

You shouldn't ever do something like this. This creates a new instance of QList on the heap and it will never be deleted, so you have a memory leak
You should have done

```
_sections = QList< QSharedPointer<core::ITrackSection> > ();
```

instead, and it would be legal. But the most simple way is to use a copy assignment like this

```
_sections = sections
```

The problem you got is most likely related to the data you have in _sections. Maybe you are calling your methods on a null CompareTimeChannel object

Comment: "The problem you got is most likely related to the data you have in _sections." -> you mean the problem should come from `core::ITrackSection`  ?

Comment: yes i think so. The rest of the code looks fine. Maybe you are missing a virtual destructor or something

Comment: in this case, could this problem happen if both `_sections` and `section` lists are empty ?

Comment: no. But if you can't even access the size of your list, you should check if you are calling setData() on a null object

Comment: okay... so, two questions :
1) can i check if the object passed to `setData()` is `null` ?
2) i can't access the size of the `_sections` class member, declared in `CompareTimeChannel.h`, it's relevant to the parameter of `setData()` ?

Comment: i mean the CompareTimeChannel object itself may be null. Since you are doing this: `dynamic_cast<CompareTimeChannel*>(channel)->setData(sections);`, if dynamic_cast returns null it's likely we're going to get the error you are getting. Checking the return value of dynamic_cast is considered a good practice

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize sections in the constructor.
The commented line is just horribly wrong.

`new` constructs the List on the heap, then you dereference that with `*new` and the assignment implicitly calls the copy constructor of the new list on the Heap and copies that into the instance. The thing on the heap is still aruond though, so you just created a memory leak.

```
// @brief Empty constructor
 CompareTimeChannel::CompareTimeChannel()
:_sections()   // initialization default constructor.
 {
 }
```

**Edit regarding the comment:**

The QList.clear() method calls the destructors of every element of the list. At least one of your shared pointers seems not to be initialized correctly. If you need more info, please paste the code that puts stuff into _sections.

**Edit Regarding the exception:**
As I said the problem is most likely with the shared pointers not being set to anything interesting. When the SP gets destroyed it calls the destructor of its content, which must exist, otherwise it throws a read access violation, which would explain the symptoms.

Comment: "The commented line is just horribly wrong." Ahah :) 

But I get the same error, but on `_sections.append(sections);` now
=>
Exception at 0x300c78d, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x4, flags=0x0

Comment: Okay... but, i don't want to destruct all objects inside the list, just remove items from the list, according to the QList documentation.

The code that feeds sections (named _sec in this class) :

      void GraphModel::addSection(const QSharedPointer<core::ITrackSection> & section)
      {
            _mutex.lock();
            _selectionUpdated = true;

            _sec << section;

            _condition.wakeOne();
            _mutex.unlock();
}

Comment: I understand, but i don't see why SharedPointers get destroyed... or `QList::clear` is not the method i need...

Now, let me replace the `setData` method with :

       `void CompareTimeChannel::setData(const QList< QSharedPointer<core::ITrackSection> > & sections)
       {
              qDebug() << "Size:" << _sections.size();
       }`

I get the same error, just by reading...

Answer (score 0):

This what you showed should work. Your problem is in some other place.
This kind of problems might be caused by many different mistakes, like: bad `static_cast` or bad c-style cast, break in binary compatibility when you are using dynamic libraries, write outside of table, problems with compiler cache (this happens is quite often so cure for that is below).

First what I would try to do:

```
make clean
qmake
make
```

This fixes such problem quite often. if i doesn't help you have to find other problems in your code.

Comment: I'll try.
I don't known if it's relevant, but the setData() method is called this way :
`dynamic_cast<CompareTimeChannel*>(channel)->setData(sections);`